# Mapping non-convex functions onto convex functions

Tags: convex-optimization, function-and-relation-composition

I am wondering if a non-convex optimization problem can be reduced to a convex one by mapping non-convex functions/sets onto convex functions/sets. In this context, I would like to know if the following claim is true:

> For any non-convex function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ there exists a convex function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $f\circ g$ is convex.

For example, $f = \log(x)$ is not convex but $g(x) = \exp(x)$ (which is convex) yields  $(f\circ g) (x) = x$ also convex.

Another example is $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) =
\begin{cases}
-x,  & \text{if $x < 0$} \\[2ex]
x, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$

**EDIT:** $g$ constant is a trivial solution, but I am not interested in this case.

Comment: I presume $g$ surjective?

Comment: just a side comment with a clarification. $\log(x)$ is a concave function. So, negated concave should yield convex, agree?

Comment: Any *constant* function $g$ would do that, but you are probably looking for strictly monotonic (injective) functions.

Comment: @MartinR  Thanks for your reply, but I am not interested  in the trivial solution $g$ constant.

Comment: @user550103, I agree, but it is just an example. It does not work if $f$ is not concave.

Comment: @AlexSilva Do you have a better example instead of such a simple concave function? some other non-convex function that is mapped to a convex function?

Comment: @user550103, $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases} -x,  ~\text{if}~  x < 0\\ x, ~\text{if}~ x \geq 0 \end{cases}$.

Comment: The reason why it can't be true in a meaningful way is the reason why convex optimization is nice: local minima of a convex function are global minima, i.e. if there is some $x$ and some neigbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(y)\ge f(x)$ for all $y\in U$, then $f(y)\ge f(x)$ for all $y$. If $f$ takes distinct values in many distinct local minima, then $f\circ g$ must "forget" that topological obstruction. A convex function covers intervals as a homeomorphism, as a $\cup$-thing or as a $\setminus\underline\quad/$-thing. So $f\circ g$ can't forget about those local minima (unless $g$ avoids them).

Comment: @AlexSilva: Ok, I see. Probably, this example should be added as an example in the above problem.

Comment: @user550103, I added it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any *constant* function $g$ would do that, but that is useless for
optimization problems.

If we add the condition that $g$ is not constant then the answer
is *no,* even for functions defined on (finite or infinite)
intervals.  More precisely:

> Let $I, J \subset \Bbb R$ be intervals, and $g: I \to J$ a
>   non-constant convex function. Then there is a continuous function
>   $f: J \to \Bbb R$ such that $f \circ g$ is not convex.

The idea is that a convex function assumes it maximum on any closed
interval at one of the boundary points of the interval, and that this
property is preserved under an (injective) change of variable.

*Proof:* W.l.o.g. assume that $g(x_0) < g(x_1)$ for some $x_0 < x_1$. 
The convexity of $g$ implies that $g$ is strictly increasing on any
interval $[x_1, x_2]  \subset I$. Then $g$ maps $[x_1, x_2]$ bijectively
onto $[y_1, y_2] := [g(x_1), g(x_2)] \subset J$.

Now we can define $f: J \to \Bbb R$ as
$$
f(y) = \sin\left( \pi \frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}\right) \, .
$$

If  $f \circ g$ were convex then
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \max \{ f(y) \mid y_1 \le y \le y_2 \} 
 &= \max \{ (f\circ g)(x) \mid  x_1 \le x \le x_2 \} \\
 &= \max( (f\circ g)(x_1), (f\circ g)(x_2) ) \\
 &= \max(f(y_1), f(y_2)) \\
 & = 0
\end{aligned}
$$

and that is not obviously not the case.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $f$ is bounded. Then $f\circ g$ is bounded and convex, so it is constant.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)=x\sin x$ and $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is convex and not constant, then $f\circ g$ is not convex. If $g$ is a convex function defined on $\Bbb R$, call $Q_g=\left\{x\in\Bbb \,:\, g(x)\ne \inf\limits_{y\in\Bbb R}g(y)\right\}=(-\infty, a)\cup (b,\infty)$ (for some $-\infty\le a\le b\le\infty)$. Let's say $b<\infty$. By convexity, $\left.g\right\rvert_{(b,\infty)}:(b,\infty)\to \left(\inf\limits_{t\in\Bbb R}g(t),\infty\right)=(u,\infty)$ is a homeomorphism. If $f\circ g$ were convex, then $h=f\circ \left.g\right\rvert_{(b,\infty)}$ would be too. In particular (being convex on an interval), it would satisfy this topological property:

> For all $x$, $h(x)=\min\limits_{t\in\operatorname{dom}h} h(t)$ if and only if there is an open set $U\ni x$ such that $h(x)=\min\limits_{t\in U} h(t)$.

This property is invariant under composition on the right by a homeomorphism. This would imply that $h\circ\left. g\right\rvert_{(b,\infty)}^{-1}=\left.f\right\rvert_{(u,\infty)}$ has it. Which is not the case, because $x\sin x$ has infinitely many local minima in any neighbourhood of $\infty$ (each attaining different values).